# How to send values from inputs to AutoLogin class in Liferay

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, autologin

I am developing a LinkedIn login hook following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787586/how-do-i-use-autologin-in-liferay) example but I got stuck at passing parameters from my .jsp file to the .java class implementing `AutoLogin`.

If I write a portlet, the values are sent correctly to a `processAction` method, however here the same approach is not working.

In my `linkedin.jsp` file i have the following (simplified) structure.

```
<%
PortletURL linkedInRegiserURL = renderResponse.createActionURL();
linkedInRegiserURL.setParameter(ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME, "linkedInRegister");
%>

<form id="linkedInForm" action="<%= linkedInRegiserURL.toString() %>" method="post"
        name='<portlet:namespace/>linkedInForm'>
    <input type="hidden" name='<portlet:namespace/>email' id="email" />
</form>
```

And then inside a `javascript` method, based on the `LinkedIn API`, I populate my input and then submit the form.

```
document.getElementById('email').value = member.emailAddress;
document.getElementById('linkedInForm').submit();
```

Everything is fine here. The problems start inside the `login()` function in my `LoginHook implements AutoLogin` class. If I do a print test, the following results are shown:

```
@Override
public String[] login(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws AutoLoginException {

    String email1 = ParamUtil.getString(request, "email");
    String email2 = request.getParameter("email");
    String email3 = request.getAttribute("email").toString();

    System.out.println("email1 : " + email1); //empty value
    System.out.println("email2 : " + email2); //null
    System.out.println("email3 : " + email3); //null

    //etc.
}
```

I guess that the problems start here `<form id="linkedInForm" action="<%= linkedInRegiserURL.toString() %>"`, but I am not sure and I don't know how should I pass my email parameter.

PS: I am working with Liferay 5.2.3, so writing a class extending `BaseStrutsPortletAction` is out of the question.

Comment: Is linkedin.jsp your custom jsp? Where is it placed? Is it part of jsp hook or entirely new custom portlet?

Comment: Yes, it is my custom jsp, part of my authentication-hook. It is included in `navigation.jspf` like this : `<c:if test="<%= showLinkedIn %>">
    <li>
     <%@include file="/html/portlet/login/linkedIn.jsp" %>  
    </li>
   </c:if>`

Comment: Ok, can you try this. Can you manually hit the URL in browser something like this and see if your AutoLogin class gets it. The format would be something like this http:/URLOfPortal/?email=abc@xyz.com

Answer (score 1):

Params Inside login hooks in Liferay are a bit tricky, you can try 2 things:

Use the following function  to retrive the "real" request wich may contains your parameter (Although I´´m not really sure if it´s available in liferay 5.2.3, in Liferay 6 its works):

PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest((javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request)

Try with a GET call , instead a POST.

Another way to do it is to save the email as a cookie( in javascript) and then recover it in the autologin hook.

Hope it do some help...