# login link to liferay with openid authentication

Tags: liferay, openid

I have a big issue with a scenario I am implementing, any help/pointers would be highly appreciated.

The scenario is as follows:

1. User login to system 1 which is an OpenId provider for liferay portal
2. User is being presented with a link which contains OpenId identity and an id
3. User press the link and a new browser tab is being opened and the user is being logged into liferay portal if not authenticated redirect to system1 login page
4. authenticate process must be done through OpenId and fetch some data from the OpenId identity provider

I found  that I should use a hook that implements AutoLogin for comming for liferay and there is no problem.

The problem is authentication with OpenId and fetching data from OpenId

Can anyone help me about OpenId and how it can be integrated with Liferay

---

Hi every one and thanks for responses.
I used this link [use autologin in liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787586/how-do-i-use-autologin-in-liferay) 
and then used this class 4 openid [RegistrationService.java class](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/svn/aselect/tags/aselect-1.9.7%20release/src/org/aselect/authspserver/authsp/openid/RegistrationService.java) and open id works correctly now the the problem is that in this login link we have some parameters that we have to use in other war file how can i store this parameter in session and then retrieve after authenticate with openid?
regards

Comment: Can show us at least what have you tried?

Comment: Seconding Christian: Please give more information on what you tried. Also, what's wrong with Liferay's out-of-the-box implementation of OpenId? Which aspect of that can't you use so that you're implementing your own solution?

Comment: So I searched a bit and find the fact that liferay has an OpenIdAutoLogin class.
Now I was wondering:
    how can I modify and use OpenIdAutoLogin to solve openid authentication and redirect to system.regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in Session Sharing between Portlet and Servlet it works on liferay 6.1.1
First I enable the Private portlet session by Adding the following tag in the liferay-portlet.xml
        `<private-session-attributes>true</private-session-attributes>`

To share the session between portal and portlet. Define the shared session attribute in portal-ext.properties file by configuring the following property in the property file
          `session.shared.attributes= LIFERAY_SHARED_ , APP_SHARED_`

and then in servlet class of hook module

> HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
>   session.setAttribute("APP_SHARED_test",testValue);

and then in your controller you can get value of  APP_SHARED_test

> String verCode= (String)actionRequest.getPortletSession().getAttribute("APP_SHARED_ver_code",PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);