# Liferay Kerberos SSO integration don't work

Tags: liferay, kerberos

I will skip `kerberos` configuration because I am certain that it works. I made a test with checking `PHP $_SERVER` variable, and everything was set.

1. Apache configuration:

LoadModule auth_kerb_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_kerb.so

```
<VirtualHost localhost:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /opt/keys/localhost.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/keys/private.pem
  SSLProxyEngine On
  SSLProxyVerify none
  SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
  ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
  <Location / >
    SSLRequireSSL
    AuthType Kerberos
    KrbMethodNegotiate On
    KrbMethodK5Passwd Off
    KrbServiceName HTTP/localhost@example.com
    KrbAuthRealms example.com
    Krb5KeyTab /etc/krb5.keytab
    require valid-user
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

2. Tomcat configuration

   `< Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
       maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
       SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"
       keystoreFile="/opt/keys/keystore.jks"
       keystorePass="changeit" />`
3. Setting creating project with mvn archetype `HOOK`, named `Kerberos-Hook`, and then create in `src/main/java` class in package `com.liferay.portal.security.auth.KerberosAutoLogin.java`:

   ```
   public class KerberosAutoLogin implements AutoLogin {

   private static Log logger = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(KerberosAutoLogin.class);

   public String[] handleException(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response, Exception e) 
           throws AutoLoginException {
       logger.error("1");
       return doHandleException(request, response, e);
   }

   protected String[] doHandleException(
           HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
           Exception e)
       throws AutoLoginException {
       logger.info("2");

       if (request.getAttribute(AutoLogin.AUTO_LOGIN_REDIRECT) == null) {
           throw new AutoLoginException(e);
       }

       logger.error("doHandleException: " + e);

       return null;
   }

   public String[] login(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
           throws AutoLoginException {
       logger.error("3");
       try {
           return doLogin(req, res);
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
           return handleException(req, res, e);
       }
   }

   protected String[] doLogin(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
   throws AutoLoginException, Exception {
       logger.error("4");
       String[] credentials = null;
       String userName = (String) req.getAttribute("REMOTE_USER");
       logger.info("kerberosUserName = " + userName);

       userName = userName.replaceAll("@.*", "").replaceAll("/.*", "");
       logger.info("userName = " + userName);

           long companyID = PortalUtil.getCompanyId(req);
           logger.info("CompanyID = " + companyID);

           if (userName == null || userName.length() < 1) {
               return credentials;
           } else {
               credentials = new String[3];

               User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByScreenName(companyID, userName);
               long userID = user.getUserId();
               String userPassword = user.getPassword();
               logger.info("userID = " + userID);

               credentials[0] = String.valueOf(userID);
               credentials[1] = userPassword;
               credentials[2] = Boolean.FALSE.toString();

               return credentials; 
           }
   }
   }
   ```
4. Configuring `liferay-hook.xml` to point to `src/main/resources/ext-portal.properties` which contain `auto.login.hooks=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.KerberosAutoLogin`
5. Create project with mvn archetype `Ext` and in project `ext-impl` create class `com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.java`
6. Deployed `HOOK` and `EXT`

in the `KerberosAutoLogin` class I put some `logs` in order to see somekind of a `debug` because I deploy application on remote server so I am not able to debug the hook properly.

However logs are not being displayed, so the class is not even used, can anyone point me what Am I missing in order to start integrating my liferay with kerberos?

In apache log I see for example:

`localhost:443 192.168.24.73 - mithrand1r@example.com [11/Feb/2016:09:56:57 +0100] "POST /poller/receive HTTP/1.1" 200 1011 "https://localhost/group/control_panel/manage/-/server/log-levels/update-categories?refererPlid=20184" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"`

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are missing liferay-hook.xml file configuration.

Please see answer for [How do I use autologin in liferay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787586/how-do-i-use-autologin-in-liferay), namely "Registering the autologin class" section.

From the configuration it also looks you introduced a security vulnerability using `ProxyPass / https://localhost:8443/`.

Try to go to https://yourserver/api/axis, you should not see list of services. If you see the list of services you are vulnerable. Then please use AJP connector `ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/`. For more info please see http://topolik-at-work.blogspot.cz/2013/02/http-modproxy-liferay-same-server.html

Comment: Thank You about pointing out vulerability. I have changed ProxyPass, and It works better I guess (no problem with redirecting to port 8443), I also made sure that the liferay-hook.xml is being registered properly. `root@liferay:/opt/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6# grep -r "KerberosAutoLogin" .
./tomcat-7.0.62/temp/5-Kerberos-Hook-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/ext-portal.properties:auto.login.hooks=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.KerberosAutoLogin`

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the value in auto.login.hook property? It is mandatory to indicate Liferay what AutoLogin classes has to use, something like this:

```
auto.login.hooks=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.KerberosAutoLogin
```

Anyway, I used a hook like you and it didn't work for me neither. So I tried to use the class in a ext-plugin project and that worked (of course, you have to set the auto.login.hook property with your AutoLogin class anyway).

Comment: I did it also. I made a Hook, deployed it and then I created Ext archetype project, in ext-impl I have made class `com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.java` but it doesnt work also

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that proxy forwarding through http/https includes all the information that Apache httpd has received. As @topolik as suggested in his answer to use ajp, this is a better starting point to make sure that all headers and request state is forwarded to tomcat. Monitor the connection between httpd and tomcat and see what goes through the line.

When the proxy creates its own http(s) request, there's nothing that I'm aware of that mandates that all request state must be forwarded. In fact, typically tomcat will receive "localhost" as the hostname unless you add `ProxyPreserveHost On` to your configuration. This is a lot more trivial than all the Kerberos settings.

I suspect they get lost at your Apache httpd, provided you're not only sure that they're there, but rather extra extra *extra* sure.

Speaking of extra extra *extra* sure: You mention `ext-portal.properties`, while Liferay's standard is `portal-ext.properties`. Check the logs to make sure your configuration file is picked up by Liferay, and make sure it's named correctly.

Comment: I have changed ProxyPass from `https` to `ajp`. About properties file, Im not sure if they are being picked up properly, but I am sure that they are being deployed properly: `tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/Kerberos-Hook-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/ext-portal.properties`

Comment: good to see the question now updated - thanks. (Note that now, contrary to your initial configuration, the connection between Apache httpd and your tomcat is no longer encrypted - you'll need to trust your network for this to happen. If it's on localhost, that's probably less of a problem)

Answer (score 0):

It looked that It was my misunderstoonding how `Kerberos SSO` work in `liferay` and I was missing including `mod_jk.conf` inside of `apache2.conf`

according to http://blog.dbi-services.com/kerberos-sso-with-liferay-61/

```
[root mod_auth_kerb-5.4]# cd ..
[root opt]# wget http://mirror.switch.ch/mirror/apache/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/tomcat-connectors-1.2.40-src.tar.gz
[root opt]# tar -xvf tomcat-connectors-1.2.40-src.tar.gz
[root opt]# cd tomcat-connectors-1.2.40-src/native
[root native]# ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --enable-api-compatibility
[root native]# make
[root native]# make install
```

and

```
[root opt]# vi /opt/liferay-6.1.1/tomcat/conf/mod_jk.conf
    LoadModule jk_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_jk.so
    JkWorkersFile /opt/liferay-6.1.1/tomcat-7.0.27/conf/workers.properties
    JkLogFile /usr/local/apache2/logs/mod_jk.log
    JkLogLevel debug
    JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
    # JkOptions indicate to send SSL KEY SIZE,
    JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
    # JkRequestLogFormat set the request format
    JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
    JkMount / ajp13
    JkMount /* ajp13

[root opt]# vi /opt/liferay-6.1.1/tomcat/conf/workers.properties
    # Define 1 real worker named ajp13
    worker.list=ajp13
    worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
    worker.ajp13.host=localhost
    worker.ajp13.port=8009
    worker.ajp13.lbfactor=50
    worker.ajp13.cachesize=10
    worker.ajp13.cache_timeout=600
    worker.ajp13.socket_keepalive=1
```